# Disable warnings for scala compilation in gradle

Tags: scala, gradle

How to disable warning for scala compilation in gradle?
The below does not work:

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
  list.add('-nowarn')
  additionalParameters = list
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such property as `ScalaCompile.additionalParameters`. Unless you are using a very old Gradle version, this should result in a "dynamic property" warning, which typically indicates a problem with the build script. Try:

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-nowarn"]
}
```

For further details, check out `ScalaCompile` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code to do the full trick for me was this:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
        scalaCompileOptions.deprecation = false
        scalaCompileOptions.unchecked = false
        scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ['-nowarn']
        options.warnings = false
        options.compilerArgs = ['-XDignore.symbol.file']
    }
}
```